Use or omission of the article "the"
I came across this the other day. Is either way acceptable or is one way preferrable?

Judy Noname defeated defending champion Michelle Kwan in a skating event.
or
Judy Noname defeated the defending champion Michelle Kwan in a skating event.

It seems to me this could be handled either way but with the simpler (1.) omission of "the" being preferable. A zero-article rule. Any thoughts?

Both are acceptable, and the meaning is the same, although the grammatical structure is different.

Judy Noname defeated defending champion Michelle Kwan in a skating event

"defending champion" is an adjectival phrase modifying the direct object of the sentence which is "Michelle Kwan".

Judy Noname defeated the defending champion Michelle Kwan in a skating event.

The direct object of the sentence is "the champion", "defending" is an adjective, and the name Michelle Kwan provides additional identification, just like a parenthetical (it will often be set apart by parentheses or commas)

Thank you. So with (2), it would be common to use: Judy Noname defeated the defending champion, Michelle Kwan, in a skating event? That makes sense. I just wanted to make sure whether both were correct to use. I'd swear I was taught in elementary school not to use "the" in this case, but that was the 60s/early-70s and a lot of grammar rules have changed since then per all my nieces and nephews school books.

@Randall That's exactly correct.

Thank you again sir.
